# How can I split string into array of string that take two characters with including the previous last character?

Tags: c#, .net, split

I have this word and I would like to split it into arrays with taking the last previous character in every iteration of split .

```
string word = "HelloWorld!";
string[] mystringarray = word.Select(x => new string(x, 2)).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(mystringarray);
```

Output result :

```
[HH,ee,ll,oo,WW,oo,rr,ll,dd,!!]
```

Expected result :

```
[He,el,ll,lo,ow,wo,or,rl,ld]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `new string(x, n)` creates a string by taking `x` and repeating it `n` times, so it's not surprising that you're seeing the result you're seeing. Try using `Substring`

Comment: Yes I confirm this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a LINQ solution, you could use [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___1___2__):

```
string[] mystringarray = word
    .Zip(word.Skip(1), (a, b) => $"{a}{b}")
    .ToArray();
```

This zips each character in `word` with itself, using `Skip` as an offset, and still has `O(n)` complexity as with an explicit loop.

Comment: Nice! I also tried to find something 'fluent' using Linq but didn't have the `Zip` method in mind.

Answer (score 3):

```
string word = "HelloWorld!";
List<string> mystringarray = new();

for (int i = 1; i < word.Length; i++)
{
    mystringarray.Add(word.Substring(i-1, 2));
}
```

Contents of `mystringarray`:

```
List<string>(10) { "He", "el", "ll", "lo", "oW", "Wo", "or", "rl", "ld", "d!" }
```

Note the exclamation mark which I'm not sure you wanted to include.

Comment: Thank you , but is there any solution more simple than this , using Linq for example?

Comment: I'm sorry, _more simple_??  Is `string[] mystringarray = word.Select(x => new string(x, 2)).ToArray();` that much more simple than `for (int i = 1; i < word.Length; i++) mystringarray.Add(word.Substring(i-1, 2));` (the braces are not needed).  The `.Zip` suggestion you have accepted is much harder for my old eyes to read and understand.  When I think _Simple_, it think _easy to understand_

Comment: In these days , I'm familiar with Linq and I have seen that it's much simpler than other methods

Comment: Minor comment; OP wants an array, not a list, so you could initialise like: `var mystringarray = new string[word.Length - 1];`, then assign in your loop like: `mystringarray[i - 1] = word.Substring(i - 1, 2);`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the following code implements the output you want.
Its algorithm is :

```
(0, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 3),
......
```

---

```
 string[] mystringarray = word.
         Select((x,i) => 
                i == 0 || i + 1 == word.Length ? x.ToString() : x + word.Substring(i,1))
        .ToArray();
```

Or use `Enumerable.Range`

```
string[] mystringarray2 = Enumerable.Range(0, word.Length).
      Select(i => i == 0 || i + 1 == word.Length ? word[i].ToString() : word[i] + word.Substring(i,1))
     .ToArray();
```

Comment: This includes an element `""`, which I don't think OP wants?

Comment: Gives an out-of-range error for the last character. Null can be used instead.

Comment: That now includes a `null`, which I don't think OP wants. You could solve that with a well-placed `Skip(1)` or `SkipLast`

Comment: As a general approach, though, this is pretty ugly. You're calling `word.Select` to map each character to something else, but you don't actually use `x` at all: you're just after the index. You'd be slightly better off with `Enumerable.Range` there, but it still ends up being a bit ugly